# Building an array filter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of information about people in the format:

```
const people = [
  {
    "name": "Bernardus de Causmaecker",
    "sex": "m",
    "born": 1721,
    "died": 1789,
    "father": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
    "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
    "sex": "m",
    "born": 1696,
    "died": 1724,
    "father": "Carel de Causmaecker",
    "mother": "Joanna Claes"
  },
  {
    "name": "Livina Haverbeke",
    "sex": "f",
    "born": 1696,
    "died": 1724,
    "father": "Father Name 1",
    "mother": "Mother Name 1"
  }
];
```

Here is the task I have been set:

> Write a filter factory `createIsMyParentFilter` that takes the string name - the person's name and returns a callback that will be used to filter the array to find the parents of the person with the given name.
>
> Parents are objects from the people array whose names match `person.mother` or `person.father`

This is what I currently have:

```js
    const people = [
      {
        "name": "Bernardus de Causmaecker",
        "sex": "m",
        "born": 1721,
        "died": 1789,
        "father": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
        "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
        "sex": "m",
        "born": 1696,
        "died": 1724,
        "father": "Carel de Causmaecker",
        "mother": "Joanna Claes"
      },
      {
        "name": "Livina Haverbeke",
        "sex": "f",
        "born": 1696,
        "died": 1724,
        "father": "Father Name 1",
        "mother": "Mother Name 1"
      }
    ];
    
    function createIsMyParentFilter(name) {
      return function(person) {
        return person.mother === name || person.father === name;
      };
    }

    console.log(
      people.filter(
        createIsMyParentFilter('Bernardus de Causmaecker')
      )
    );
```

However this returns an empty array; why is that?

Comment: Can you add more context? Why is this not working, do you want the function to be used in `array.sort(createIsMyParentFilter(name))` or something else?

Comment: Just a friendly tip for your next question - try to include the problem in the title. In this title, you are polite but provide no information. You can skip the greeting and get straight to the point - minimum words and maximum information :)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know why it doesn't work. I just want to know what options there are for this task.

Comment: Your approach there is logically wrong to begin with. You are not supposed to look for a person whose mother or father have the given `name` - you are supposed to look for the mother and father of the person, who has that name. So if the given name was `Lieven de Causmaecker`, then you'd need to find the 2nd person in your given example data first of all - and then you need to find the two persons named `Carel de Causmaecker` and `Joanna Claes` in your array, and return _those_.

Comment: @CBroe is quite right here - you have inverted the problem. You need first to obtain the object containing the person matching `name` to start off with, because you need to look up their `.father` and `.mother`. You can do this by changing your factory function signature to `function createIsMyParentFilter(name, people)`, where `people` is your array list of everyone. (Your solution is treating the passed person as a parent, but in fact the problem regards them as a child, and we are looking for their parents).

Comment: Your current code returns an empty array because the filter doesn't match anyone, as there is no one with `mother` or `father` equal to 'Bernardus de Causmaecker'. I think the question should remain closed.

Comment: @НазарКоломиец: how are you getting on with this? Have you got it working on your own machine now?

Answer (score 0):

The attempt you have provided tackles the problem in the wrong way, so to get to the solution we need to reassess what the filter function should do.

The problem statement says that the filter factory needs to accept a name, and the filter it creates needs to return the parents of the person of the supplied name. So we know that if the factory is given "Bernardus de Causmaecker" the filter should return the person objects for "Lieven de Causmaecker" and "Livina Haverbeke".

In your solution, the filter function will be presented with every person in the array, it will return any person records where the name given to the factory is either the current person's mother or the current person's father. Thus "Bernardus de Causmaecker" will return no records because this person is not recorded in your data as anyone's parent (of either gender).

So to accomplish this task we have to first retrieve the person record for the name given to the factory. From there we then have access to the father and mother properties, which can be used in the filter. The code looks like this:

```js
const people = [
  {
    "name": "Bernardus de Causmaecker",
    "sex": "m",
    "born": 1721,
    "died": 1789,
    "father": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
    "mother": "Livina Haverbeke"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lieven de Causmaecker",
    "sex": "m",
    "born": 1696,
    "died": 1724,
    "father": "Carel de Causmaecker",
    "mother": "Joanna Claes"
  },
  {
    "name": "Livina Haverbeke",
    "sex": "f",
    "born": 1696,
    "died": 1724,
    "father": "Father Name 1",
    "mother": "Mother Name 1"
  }
];

function createIsMyParentFilter(name, people) {
  const thisPerson = people.find((person) => person.name === name);
  console.log(`Mother = ${thisPerson.mother}, father = ${thisPerson.father}`);
  return function(person) {
    return person.name === thisPerson.father || person.name === thisPerson.mother;
  }
}

console.log(
  people.filter(createIsMyParentFilter('Bernardus de Causmaecker', people))
);
```

The handy thing with this factory is that it sets up a local context (of the `thisPerson` variable) that is retained by the resulting filter. So the end statement where the `filter` is activated, the `thisPerson` value is no longer locally accessible, but it can still be used internally by the filter.